# Change ggplot legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I am relatively new using the ggplot package. I want to rename the legend of a plot using the names "Sp1" and "Sp2". I have tried to make it using the following code but I have been unable to do it.

This is the code:

```
t<-read.table ("covartimesfinal2.txt", header=T)

attach(t)

p <- ggplot(t,aes(x=Ratio,y=Time)) + geom_point(aes(shape=factor(Sp)))

p + geom_smooth(aes(linetype=factor(Sp), ),colour="black", method='lm', 

se=F)+theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = 

element_line(colour = "black"))+

scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Species",labels=c("Sp1", "Sp2"))
```

My aim is to get rid of the legend named "factor(Sp)" and make the numbers of the axis black and not grey.

Thanks in advance! Please find attached a sample plot

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your task looks quite easy, but if you'd like a complete solution, please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding a minimal sample of your data.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide us (part of) covartimesfinal2.txt ?

Comment: Sorry! This is my first post. Is there any way to upload txt files?

Answer (score 1):

The following drops the unwanted legend labels, I created an own data example:

**Data example**

```
t<-data.frame(Ratio=c(1:10,1:10), Time=c(1:10,11:20), Sp=as.factor(c(rep("H", 10), rep("N", 10))))
```

**Ggplot**

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(t,aes(x=Ratio,y=Time, group=Sp, shape=Sp)) + geom_point() + geom_line()

p <- p + scale_shape_discrete(name="Species",labels=c("Sp1", "Sp2"))

p <- p + theme(axis.line=element_line(colour = "black"), axis.text=element_text(colour="black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed. Just for curiosity, is there a way to change line style too?